# Hold Up for Power loss of 10ms

Tags: power-supply, avr

I'm using ATMEGA644 in a measurement circuit.
I'm providing the primary supply from a battery + boost regulator and if/when the voltage (the one that I have to measure) is available I want the supply to switch to that voltage. Switching will be done using a relay. So I figured I need to hold 5V till the release time of the relay which is nearly 15ms.

I know I'll have to hold 5V at the supply pin of ATMEGA644. I think I can use a capacitor to hold 5V for 15ms but I'm not sure.

My questions are:

1. Can I use a capacitor to hold 5V for a current flow of 50mA? If yes, then what will be the circuit and how will I be able to calculate the capacitance?
2. If not then what circuit should I consider following? or what other option should I be looking into?

Comment: "Switching will be done using a relay." I'm *really* curious to know why you need to use a relay in this application.

Comment: No special reason. I figured I only need a few amps at 5V

Comment: So then why not use one of the several power switching schemes that *don't* have a cutover delay?

Comment: Um. Is using relay a bad option? I have some in spare I don't want to spend more

Comment: When the secondary vltage is available why not use it to charge the primary battery then you don't need to switch.

Answer (score 1):

.If you must use a 15ms relay then you need a cap just like you said .The tolerable voltage drop which occurs while the cap discharges slightly during the 15ms        outage,so I will assume that 250mV drop is OK .Then to the nearest preferred Value we get 3300 microfarad .

Comment: Could you please tell me how you calculated that value ?

Comment: Could you please explain to me how you calculated this value?